# How to process all messages between two timestamps with Spring Kafka?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm trying to create a command-line Spring Kafka app that processes all records for a particular topic between two timestamps, and then shuts down.

I've learnt that, to get my app to start consuming from `startTimestamp`, my listener should implement the `ConsumerSeekAware` interface and override the `onPartitionsAssigned` member.

I am unsure, however, how to gracefully shut down the application after processing a record with a timestamp outside of the period defined by `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp`.

```
@Component
public class Listener implements ConsumerSeekAware {

  private final long startTimestamp;
  private final long endTimestamp;

  public Listener(long startTimestamp, long endTimestamp) {
    this.startTimestamp = startTimestamp;
    this.endTimestamp = endTimestamp;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments,
      ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    callback.seekToTimestamp(assignments.keySet(), startTimestamp);
  }

  @KafkaListener(id = "my-app", topics = "my-topic")
  public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, Integer> record) {
    if (record.timestamp() > endTimestamp) {
      // shutdown application
    }
  }
}
```